# A tool to validate the structure of a Python Package?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I started writing Python code not too long ago and everything just works, but I have been having problem writing a package.  I was wondering if there is such a thing as a "package validation tool". I know, I could just start up a REPL and start importing the module but...is there a better way? Is there a tool that could tell me "you have these possible errors"?

Or maybe there is something in the middle: is there a way to test a Python's package structure?

As always, thanks in advance!

Comment: what kinds of "errors" would you like it to detect? can you give examples?  I don't think there's such thing as a "valid" package structure. Perhaps running pyflakes can be a good start?

Comment: @shx2 thanks! I didn't know about pyflakes, as you said, that's a good start. Now, the kind of error that I would like to check are stuff like the correct name on the __all__ attributes inside the __init__ files or indicating if there are __init__ files for all subfolders, stuff like that.

Comment: There is no way to check that you have the correct names on the `__all___` attributes. Only you know that.

Answer (score 1):

If you call a module using:

```
python -m module
```

Python will load/execute the module, so you should catch crude syntax errors. Also, if module has a block like:

```
if __name__ = "__main__":
    do_something()
```

It will be called. For some small self-contained modules I often use this this block to run tests.

Given the very dynamic nature of Python, it is very hard to check for correctness if the module author is not using [TTD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test-driven_development). There is no silver bullet here. There are tools that will check for "[code smells](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_smell)" and compliance with standards (dynamic languages tend to generate a profusion of [linters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lint_%28software%29)).

- [pylint](http://www.pylint.org/)
- [PyChecker](http://pychecker.sourceforge.net/)
- [PyFlakes](https://launchpad.net/pyflakes)
- [PEP8](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pep8)

A good IDE like [PyCharm](http://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/) can help, if you like IDEs.

These tools can help, but are still far from the assurance of static languages where the compiler can catch many errors at compile time. For example, [Go](http://golang.org/) seems to be designed to have a very pedantic compiler. Haskell programs are said to be like mathematical proofs.

If you are coming from a Language with strong compile time checks, just relax. Python is kind of a "throw against the wall and see if it sticks", language. Some of the Python "macho" principles:

- [duck typing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing)
- [EAFP](http://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-eafp)
- [We are all consenting adults](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/writing/style/#we-are-all-consenting-adults)

Answer (score 0):

There is no tool to test the package structure per se, and I'm unsure of what would be tested. Almost any structure is a valid structure...

But there are some tools to help you test your package **data** if you are distributing your module, they may be useful:

- [Pyroma](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyroma) will check the packages meta data.
- [check-manifest](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/check-manifest) will check the MANIFEST.in file.

I have both of them installed and also uses [zest.releaser](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/zest.releaser) which also has some basic sanity-checks. But none of these will check that the code is OK, so it won't look for the `__init__` files, for example.